# I've compiled wine on Mac, but it doesn't work, because it freezes and SEGV

Tags: macos, wine, gcc

I've compiled successfully wine sources.
Also added following line into my ~/.profile

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/X11/lib:/usr/lib"
```

because of errors like:

```
failed to load libX11.6.dylib
```

But now I've following results when running wine related binaries:

```
$ wine some.exe
err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
(freezes)
err:ntdll:RtlpWaitForCriticalSection section 0x7bc99d74 "loader.c: loader_section" wait timed out in thread 0047, blocked by 0042, retrying (60 sec)
err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000194 flags 0 addr 0x7bc29099

$ wineboot
err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out

$ winedbg
err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out
```

My versions are as follow:

```
GCC: i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
Xquartz: X.Org X Server 1.4.2-apple56 (Build Date: 20100624)
```

Possible solutions which didn't help:

```
$ wineboot --update
err:process:__wine_kernel_init boot event wait timed out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compile using different compiler e.g. gcc or cc (especially on the Mac, where there are some compiler related bugs). If you compiling using gcc, try to upgrade it and use the different version.

If you have already Mac ports, check which version you can install by following command:

```
sudo port select --list gcc
```

or

```
sudo port search gcc
```

Then install newer version by:

```
sudo port install gcc47 gcc_select
```

If you come across some dependencies, try to solve them by following commands (otherwise ignore them):

```
sudo port install libbonoboui libglade2 gobject-introspection
sudo port upgrade libpixman
```

Once you have gcc_select installed, check which versions do you have currently:

```
sudo gcc_select -l
```

Then change it in example by:

```
sudo gcc_select gcc47
```

Eventually if you decide to use different compiler, change it in Makefile.

In case of some problems, make sure that you have everything up-to-date:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

Troubleshooting:

- make sure that you have installed and up-to-dated [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) which simulates *unix X windows for wine,

---

Here are some few related solutions found on WineHQ forum:

- http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=15519
- http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=16091&p=78499

Comment: In my case it worked after I've downloaded the recent XQuartz (2.7.2) and run it, then winecfg started to work.